# Mixin partial and variables partial not detected when scss is compiled. Error: Undefined Mixin and Partial

Tags: css, sass, compilation

My `_variables.scss` and `_mixins.scss` partials do not seem to be picked up when I compile my Sass files. My `_globals.scss` and `_header.scss` are picked up fine, even though they are in the same directory and accessed the same way.

In my `style.scss` file:

```
@use "globals";
@use "header";
```

Terminal error messages:

```
Error: Undefined mixin.
@include breakpoint-down(medium){display: none;}

Error: Undefined variable.
color: $grayishBlue;
```

I used a package.json code to compile my sass, with a few tweaks. Here is what mine looks like:

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "SASS compile|autoprefix|minimize and live-reload dev server using Browsersync for static HTML",
    "main": "public/index.html",
    "author": "5t3ph",
    "scripts": {
      "build:sass": "sass  --no-source-map src/sass:public/css",
      "copy:images": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/images/**/* public",
      "copy:html": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/*.html public",
      "copy": "npm-run-all --parallel copy:*",
      "watch:images": "onchange 'src/images/**/*' -- npm run copy:html",
      "watch:html": "onchange 'src/*.html' -- npm run copy:html",
      "watch:sass": "sass  --no-source-map --watch src/sass:public/css",
      "watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
      "serve": "browser-sync start --server public --files public",
      "start": "npm-run-all copy --parallel watch serve",
      "build": "npm-run-all copy:html build:*",
      "postbuild": "postcss public/css/*.css -u autoprefixer cssnano -r --no-map"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
      "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
      "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
      "cssnano": "^5.0.17",
      "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
      "onchange": "^7.1.0",
      "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
      "sass": "^1.49.8"
    }
  }
```

`_globals.scss` file:

```
@use "variables";
@use "mixins";

html {
    font-size: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Public Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: $grayishBlue; //if i comment out this line, i get an error //for mixins.
    line-height: 1.3;
}
// and so on... until we get to the styles that use the mixin.

//Visibility
.hide-for-mobile {
    // hide for mobile and tablet
    @include breakpoint-down(medium){
        display: none;
    }
}

.hide-for-desktop {
    //hide for desktop viewport widths
    @include breakpoint-up(large){
        display: none;
    }
}
```

`_header.scss` file:

```
@use "variables";

.header {

    nav {
        padding: 24px;
    }

//and so on... variables are used twice in this module.
```

File hierarchy in the sass folder is as follows:

```
 - sass
   - _globals.scss
   - _header.scss
   - _mixins.scss
   - _variables.scss
   - style.css
   - style.css.map
   - style.scss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [in the doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#loading-members):

> Members (variables, functions, and mixins) loaded with @use are only visible in the stylesheet that loads them. Other stylesheets will need to write their own @use rules if they also want to access them.

Which means that in order to read your variables and mixins, you need to import them directly in the files that use them and not on your global styles file.

On `_globals.scss` and `_header.scss` add:

```scss
@use "variables" as *;
@use "mixins" as *;
```

Additionally, if you don't want to import both files every time, you can create a new file that will [forward](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward) them and then import only this file:

```scss
// _settings.scss (or any other name)
@forward "variables";
@forward "mixins";
```

```scss
// _globals.scss & _header.scss
@use "settings" as *;
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but still get the error. I will update the question to include more details.

Comment: One thing I do know is that I don't know what <url> means in @use <url>. Is it a relative path to the scss file from current directory?

Comment: @Kazuya If you don't use the [namespaces](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace) you need to add `as *` after the imports. Here is [the part of the doc about paths](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#load-paths). Just try to read the doc more carefully, I swear all the solutions to your problems are here. :)